# Injecting Contact Created in SF on Child BU Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sobject, marketing-cloud-connect

I created a Journey in Child BU that uses SF Object Contacts as entry and trigger whenever a Contact Is created. So i tested creating contact and see if it is being accepted under the Child BU JB, but its seems that is it not being injected and accepted. I have setup the MC configuration in  SF on choosing the parent and child BU. What could be the reasons as to why the contacts are not being injected on the child JB? Is it possible to inject SF Contact Object to Child BU? Multi Org is not turned on the Account.

My Entry Criteria as Follows:

WHO
Contact ID (Contact)
OBJECT
Contact
ACTION
Created;
CRITERIA
Contact:Id WASSET AND Contact:Email is Not Null

Comment: Have you tried injecting it in a master BU journey? The reasons for contacts not injecting can be manifold

Comment: Is child BU integrated using marketing cloud connect as the same master BU SF Org?

Comment: @StephandePaly i tried it in Master BU and it works fine. It cant be manifold cause im using a controlled data for the purpose of testing.  During the test it was only being injected on the Child BU JB but it was not accepted. I recreated the test in main BU and it was accepted. What could had been wrong, that it is being prevented to be injected in child BU JB?

Comment: @Plug SF is only integrated in Main BU as multi-org is not enabled. Child BU should inherit the setup in the Main BU.

Comment: @m.dacillo Can you check Journey history tab and filter your journey and see if you can narrow down issues? Do you see any logs there at all?

Comment: hey @plug there will be no history as no contact has been injected, no logs at all.

Comment: Have you logged a support ticket?

Comment: yes will update here once issue has been resolve

Comment: @StephandePaly So here how was the issue was resolve, in clearing invalid token(s) there are two types one for Salescloud User and API User,  the issue here is that since there where two BU: clearing both API User for both BU did the trick:

If there's only one BU clearing invalid tokens using this:
Documentation: [https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214335&type=1]

If there are multiple BUs:
Documentation: [https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_clear_invalid_tokens.htm&type=5]

Answer (score 0):

When working with Multiple Business Units, Single Org Connector and Marketing Cloud Connect, you need to make sure that:

- The MC Integration User has access to All Business Units
- The SF Integration (API) User has access to all Business Units
- The Connector is configured with all the desired Business Units

Doing the above ensures that the oAuth connection is intact across BUs and journey injection can happen.

If the above is done, and it still doesn't work - then as you write in the comments - clearing tokens might be needed